# Java - One Method for Many Objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Say I've got a Java file with 500 custom objects of type `Item`. Now, say I want users to be able to add/remove any one of those objects to that list in the program. I want to try to avoid doing something like this:

```
public class Inventory {
    public static ArrayList<Item> inv = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void addItem1 {
        inv.add(Item.Item1); //Pulling from Item class
    } //addItem1()
    public static void removeItem1 {
        inv.remove(Item.Item1);
    } //removeItem1()
    public static void addItem 2 {
        . . .
    }
    . . .
}
```

By doing that, I'd have to make an add and a remove function for every single item. There will be hundreds of items, so I sincerely hope there's a better way for the user to be able to do so from inside of the program. This would further be awful because of how it would require some massive nested `switch` statements to swap out everything.

Instead I'd hope to implement a single adder method and a single remover method, that could take the user's input (a String with the literal name of the `Item` they are trying to add), and somehow find/select the `Item`. Implementation thoughts?

Comment: Maybe use a field?

Comment: what is the difference between Item1 and Item2 and so on? just the name????

Comment: By the way, use `List` rather than `ArrayList` unless absolutely necessary

Comment: RAZ makes a good point. Are these items all different classes? If they are, why can't your make all of them extend some superclass of (superitem :P) and then operate on that superclass?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz, @ifly6; these items are all similar, in that they hold at least those three base variables, though they may have more. For example, a sword is an item and a candle is an item; each have a name, price, and description, though the sword will have additional values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using generic class ?

```
public class Inventory<T> {
public static ArrayList<Item> inv = new ArrayList<>();
public void addItem (T item){
    inv.add((Item)item); // where item can be anything from Item.item1 to Item.item500
}
public void removeItem (T item){
    inv.remove((Item)item);
}
```

In that case, to see if your item is in fact an item do something similar to this: `System.out.println(item.getClass().getName()); //should return Item`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use:

```
public void setItem(Item item){
    inv.add(item);
}
```

Then use the same concept for removal.